# Accessing a specific value from an array returned by Ajax in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Ajax part

```
$("#panchayat").change(function(){
var param = {'panchayat_id':$(this).val()};
alert (param['panchayat_id']);
$.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 url : '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/parent_taluk',
 dataType : 'html',
 data: param,
 success : function(data)
    {                   
        var taluk_id='taluk_'+data;
        alert(taluk_id);
        document.getElementById(taluk_id).selected=true;

    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {                                              alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

    } 
    });
});
```

### Controller method

```
public function parent_taluk(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $Panchayat_Id= $this->input->post('panchayat_id');
    $this->check_isvalidated();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $data['taluk'] = $this->admin_model->parent_taluk_one($Panchayat_Id);
    $taluk_id=$data['taluk']->Taluk_Id;
    $taluk_name=$data['taluk']->Taluk_Name;
    echo $taluk_id;
}
```

### data echoed back from the controller

returned data is an array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Panchayat_Id] => 1050
            [Taluk_Id] => 47
            [Panchayat_Name] => Municpality
            [Taluk_Name] => Eranad
        )

)
47
```

value returned for taluk_id is an array

```
taluk_Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Panchayat_Id] => 1050
            [Taluk_Id] => 47
            [Panchayat_Name] => Municpality
            [Taluk_Name] => Eranad
        )

)
47
```

I need the [Taluk_Id] => 47  , which is 47 to be obtained form this returned value , or I need just 47 as the return value .

I am unable to get the value 47 which is returned to the ajax function from the controller . pls help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ajax returns an array of objects. Each object is a taluk object, which contains properties such as Taluk_Id, Taluk_Name, Panchayat_Id and Panchayat_Name. The following would work.

```
var res = taluk_Array.filter(function(taluk){
   return taluk.Taluk_Id===47;
});

var result = res[0];
```

now print this

```
result.Taluk_Id
result.Taluk_Name
result.Panchayat_Id
result.Panchayat_Name
```

To set this result Taluk_Id in another combo box

```
var element = document.getElementById('parentSelectCombo');
element.value = result.Taluk_Id; //47 in your case
```

Comment: Hi vivek, I need 47 to be picked up from the array  for doing this change **document.getElementById(taluk_id).selected=true;**

Comment: what is the element with id='47'? is it a checkbox?or combobox?

Comment: It is a select box , combobox .

Comment: I am a novice in handling arrays . This is for changing the parent drop down  when the user select a value in the child drop down . If I am able to retrieve the ID from the returned array I could be able to change the selected value in the parent combo. This is because , child combo lists all options for all values in the parent combo .

Comment: var element = document.getElementById('parentSelectCombo');
element.value = valueToSelect; //47 in your case

Comment: There is the problem , I don't know how to select the value 47 from this array . How to find Taluk_Id from the returned array . That's the problem . I am sorry if am confusing you .

Comment: hm. maybe in your question you have not given correct structure, if my answer did not work. can you paste a sample array element of that ajax result in ur question?

Comment: Please check "data echoed back from the controller" , I got it using firebug . From that array is it possible to get the value of  [Taluk_Id] => . It's value will always change depending on the selection of panchayat .

Comment: The problem was with the model and the question remains unanswered but the issue has been resolved for me with the use of **$("#taluk").val(data).attr('selected',true);**  Instead of array now am returning only id of the taluk to be selected from the drop down

Comment: Thank you very much for you assistance . I need to check your solution for arrays . I need to learn it .